# Java applet using JavaFx

Tags: java, swing, applet, awt, javafx-2

I'm developing an applet. I want to use JavaFx to create the controls. Currently, I'm using An JFXPanel. Here is the code:

```
private JFXPanel jfxPanel;
private Canvas canvas;
private Scene scene;
private BorderPane borderPane;

public void init() {
    jfxPanel = new JFXPanel();

    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            jfxPanel.setScene(createScene());
            add(jfxPanel);
        }
    });
}

public Scene createScene() {
    borderPane = new BorderPane();
    scene = new Scene(borderPane, 400, 800);
    canvas = new Canvas();

    canvas.getGraphicsContext2D().setFill(Color.RED);        

    borderPane.setCenter(canvas);

    return scene;
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
}
```

The problem is that it doesn't work. I can't see anything. Do you have any idea?

Comment: I advise writing a pure JavaFX application rather than embedding your JavaFX controls in Swing.  Follow the [Oracle Guide to Deploying Your First JavaFX Application](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/basic_deployment.htm) to deploy your application in a browser.  Make sure you can run the application standalone first before trying to make it work in a browser.  When something doesn't work always describe what happens when it doesn't work (e.g. exception trace) and the exact steps to make it not work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's too late to answer, but...

Try to add this line below to your init()

```
getContentPane().add(jfxPanel);
```